# Draw order in 2D as in game maker in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have the following:

```
while(1){
  ...    
  object1.draw();
  object2.draw();
}
```

Of course the second object is drawn on first. My question is if the object 1 can be drawn on the object 2 without changing the order in which they appear in the main loop.

I can do something similar as the program game maker where the depth function is used?

I use OpenGL without shaders.

Comment: Put the objects you want to draw in a list or vector, then you can resort it when you want to change the depth without having to change your drawing code.

Comment: @JonathanPotter except that he'll still have to change his code in main loop.

Comment: attach a depth buffer to your framewbuffer. This will allow OpenGL to perform depth testing. If you request to draw something that is behind another object it will be clipped. You will need to adjust your viewing frustrum (orthogonal matrix) to have a range of zvalues. This way you have more the -1 to 1 to work with.

Comment: to provide a code example. what library are you working with? you may have a depth buffer already by default.

Comment: I do not use any particular library

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Game Maker, but you can to use glFrustrum to achieve what you want in opengl.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml

set the near and far clipping planes to 0, and 100 or some other arbitrarily large number. then when you draw them specify a z-value where the second z-value is less than, i.e. closer to the camera, than the first objects z-value.

Comment: I can use the function glFrustum when I am already using the function glOrtho?